appscript Session.getActiveUserLocale not working when i tested it on my iphone
I'm working on a gmail add-on and I'm trying to get the user's local language from the gmail settings using Session.getActiveUserLocale()
The code:
function getUserLanguage() {
    const locale = Session.getActiveUserLocale();
    const userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    userProperties.setProperty('USER_LANGUAGE', locale);
    Logger.log('User locale: ' + locale);
    return locale;
}


When it is triggered in the browser, it works.
I get the "User locale: fr" for example but when I tested it on my iOS gmail app I don't get anything, it's empty and I couldn't find any reference.

It seems that Apps Script does not fully support mobile platforms[1]. (Although this link points to the Google Docs editor documentation)
It seems the onOpen() function does not work on mobile, if you are using this to run your getUserLanguage() function you could try replacing it with an installable trigger[3].
You could also try to use desktop mode from your mobile browser.
Reference Material:
[1] - Use add-ons, Apps Script, AppSheet & Looker Studio - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256
[2] - onOpen event in mobile apps
-https://b.corp.google.com/issues/36765325
[3] - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
[4] - https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/workspace-triggers
